# Positioning of span inside of input - not moving with input box on small screens

Tags: css, input, css-position

I' trying to position a magnifying glass span inside of an input box. The problem is when the browser is resized and the input box slides under the select box, the magnifying glass span stays on the top.

```
<select id="documentscomparator" class="dropdown" name="documentscomparator">
  <option value="LIKE">like</option><option value="EQUALS">equals</option>
  <option value="NOTEQUALS">not equals</option>
  <option value="GREATERTHAN">greater than</option>
  <option value="LESSTHAN">less than</option>
  <option value="BETWEEN">between</option>
  <option value="ISNULL">is null</option>
  <option value="NOTNULL">is not null</option>
  <option value="IN">in</option>
</select>

<span class="magnifyingGlass"></span>

<input type="text" value="">

span.magnifyingGlass {
    width: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3px;
    z-index: 999
}
span.magnifyingGlass:before {
    width: 1.6em;
    content: "⚲";
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: block;
}
input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative
}
```

Please see the fiddle and resize the browser to see what I mean:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaEJG.png)
https://jsfiddle.net/u0xyLxog/2/

What I got:

[[image: span outside of input box on small screen]

This is what i'd like it to look like:

[image: span positioned correctly inside of input box]

Comment: just wrap   span and input box in a div and set its position as relative  and then then adjust your css accordingly <div><span class="magnifyingGlass"></span><input type="text" value=""></div>

Comment: You are required to post your markup here within the question itself and not any third party site which can change and go dead, helping no one in the future. [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the advice, i dont use this very often, i edited the code now

Answer (score 0):

Put `input` and `span` inside an inline block with `white-space:no-wrap` so they always stick together. I have added a div with ID **oneline**. please check its styles. (Please check the snippet in full screen and resize screen to see the result.)

```css
span.magnifyingGlass {
    width: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3px;
    z-index: 999
}
span.magnifyingGlass:before {
    width: 1.6em;
    content: "⚲";
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: block;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="text"].searchable {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative
}

#oneline{
white-space:no-wrap;
display:inline-block;
}

#documentscomparator{width:400px;}
```

```html
<select id="documentscomparator" class="dropdown" name="documentscomparator">
  <option value="LIKE">like</option><option value="EQUALS">equals</option>
  <option value="NOTEQUALS">not equals</option>
  <option value="GREATERTHAN">greater than</option>
  <option value="LESSTHAN">less than</option>
  <option value="BETWEEN">between</option>
  <option value="ISNULL">is null</option>
  <option value="NOTNULL">is not null</option>
  <option value="IN">in</option>
</select>

<div id="oneline">
<span class="magnifyingGlass"></span>
<input type="text" data-storable="document-document" id="document" data-object="document-document" class="nestable searchable storable" name="document" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that table is created by javascript and I dont have access to it. Can only change the css. is there any way to do this without changing the html?

Comment: I have to search for css solution. Does a javascript solution help?

Comment: no, just css please. I think I will just have to find a way to add the div around the elements as Ali suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Almost got..
Remove the span tag before input.
Alter the css like this,

```
.magnifyingGlass::placeholder{
    width: 1.6em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
```

And add the class name 'magnifyingGlass' to the input, then set the content to the placeholder

```
<input class="magnifyingGlass" type="text" placeholder="⚲">
```

you will get text box like this(click to view output) [tested output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHBVN.png)

Now the content(search-icon) is present in the middle of the text box, i tried to align to the left. But it didn't work. I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to enter too much in detail of your implementation of magnifying glass icon, however the solution here is to wrap the input and the span in a containing div like this:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="icon">
    <span>x</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The external wrapper must have position set to relative while inner input must have width of 100%, meaning that it occupies the whole width of external wrapper.
Icon div instead requires position set to absolute and positional attributes for right and top set to 0 (it goes all the way right with respect to wrapper width). Content of this .icon div might be a span, directly a text or maybe you can use pseudo elements directly on it.

You can see a result [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0xyLxog/4/).

You can play around with wrapper class to set width and make it as long as you need.

Hope this helps.